# Connection error in spring,Hibernate with Mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, hibernate, spring-boot

I have tried to connect Spring, Hibernate with Mongodb. While trying that I got error like this I don't know what was the mistake I have done in my code so can anyone knows means please let me know.For your reference I have updated my code and error

**HibernateConfig.java**

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration  
@EnableTransactionManagement  
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfig 
{
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
@Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "io.bpk.app.entity"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }
    
    
    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider"));
        properties.put("hibernate.ogm.datastore.host", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.ogm.datastore.host"));
        properties.put("hibernate.ogm.datastore.port", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.ogm.datastore.port"));
        properties.put("hibernate.ogm.datastore.database", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.ogm.datastore.database"));
        properties.put("hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database"));
     
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }
    
}
```

**UserRepositoryImpel.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import io.bpk.app.entity.Users;

@Repository("UsersRepository")
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UsersRepository {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    @Override
    public Users create(Users usr) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        session .persist(usr);
        return usr;
    }

    @Override
    public Users findByEmail(String email) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        TypedQuery<Users> query = session.createNamedQuery("UsersFindByEmail",Users.class);
        query.setParameter("pemail", email);
        try
        {
            Users usr = query.getSingleResult();
            return usr;
        }
        catch (NoResultException nre)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Users> findAll() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        TypedQuery<Users> query = session.createNamedQuery("UsersFindAll", Users.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

**Userservices.java**

```
  package io.bpk.app.service;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
    
    import io.bpk.app.entity.Users;
    import io.bpk.app.exception.UserAlreadyExist;
    import io.bpk.app.repository.UsersRepository;
    
    @Service
    public class UsersServiceImpl implements UsersService {
    
        @Autowired
        private UsersRepository repos;
        
    
        @Override
        public Users create(Users usr) {
            Users exist = repos.findByEmail(usr.getEmail());
            if(exist!=null)
                throw new UserAlreadyExist("User already exist");
            return repos.create(usr);
        }
    
        @Override
        public List<Users> findAll() {
            return repos.findAll();
        }
    
    }
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
package io.bpk.app.repository;

import java.util.List;

import io.bpk.app.entity.Users;

public interface UsersRepository {

    public Users create(Users usr);

    public Users findByEmail(String email);

    public List<Users> findAll();

}
```

**application.properties**

```
 hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider = mongodb
 hibernate.ogm.datastore.host = localhost
 hibernate.ogm.datastore.port = 27017
 hibernate.ogm.datastore.database = local
 hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database = false
 hibernate.ogm.mongodb.authentication_database = admin
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.bpk</groupId>
    <artifactId>MongoDB-Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>MongoDB-Test</name>
    <url>https://learn.egen.io</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-redis -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-async</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.nosql</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Facing Error**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'usersServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repos': Error creating bean with name 'UsersRepository': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory': Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in io.bpk.app.HibernateConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/BootstrapContext;Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataImplementor;Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions;)V; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in io.bpk.app.HibernateConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/BootstrapContext;Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataImplementor;Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions;)V; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'UsersRepository': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory': Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in io.bpk.app.HibernateConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/BootstrapContext;Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataImplementor;Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions;)V; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in io.bpk.app.HibernateConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/BootstrapContext;Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/MetadataImplementor;Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions;)V
```

Comment: show your `UsersRepository` interface

Comment: Can you add packages to classes?

Comment: I already added all packages in code

Comment: @AndrewNepogoda I added Interface code  UserRepository.java

Comment: @Hariprasath do you have implementation of `UsersRepository`?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with the libraries versions you are using. It's hard to say without more details but, if I have to guess, you are using the wrong Hibernate ORM/OGM version for the Spring version you have in the project.

Keep in mind that Hibernate OGM uses ORM underneath and the version added to the project might not be the one you expect.

Spring 4.3.2.RELEASE is compatible with Hibernate ORM 5.2.1.Final (based on [this maven repository page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.3.2.RELEASE))
Hibernate OGM 5.4.1.Final uses Hibernate ORM 5.3.6.Final
The Hibernate OGM page has a [compatibility matrix page](http://hibernate.org/ogm/releases/5.3/)

You need to adjust your dependencies in the pom.xml accordingly. I think these changes will work with Spring 4.3.2 (I haven't tried them):

- Spring version: 4.3.2.RELEASE
- OGM version: 5.3.1.Final
- Remove Hibernate ORM dependency (OGM and Spring already include it as transitive dependency)
- Remove mongo-java-driver dependency (it's already a transitive OGM dependency)

Comment: but I added Latest version on Hibernate ORM/OGM

Comment: They all are different projects. This means that the latest versions of each of them are not automatically compatible unless there is some kind of explicit agreement to do so (there isn't). You need to check for each project which dependencies are needed and add the right version accordingly. I've updated my answer with a set of versions that should work (I haven't tried it).

Comment: I changing dependencies.but its throwing different error

Comment: **Facing Error**:
 Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in io.bpk.app.HibernateConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Comment: You need to set the persistence provider to org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence. Usually you do it in the persistence.xml, Here's a persistence.xml as an example: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-ogm/blob/master/core/src/test/resources/persistencexml/ogm.xml#L13

Comment: If you are referring to  hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider, that's the datastore provider, not the persistence provider. To setup OGM, you need to use the OgmSessionFactory or use the OgmConfiguration or set the persistence provider in persistence.xml.  Otherwise Spring will create a SessionFactory using ORM instead (I think). I'm sure there is a way to do that in Spring where you use the LocalSessionFactoryBean